# Is there a better way to write CompletableFutrue.XXXasync() invocations in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, completable-future

Java `CompletableFuture<T>` has a lot of async methods, static or instance, in this format

```
public <U> CompletableFuture<U> XXXasync(SomeFunctionalInterface<T> something, Executor executor)
```

If you have enough experience with FP in kotlin, you will immediately realize these function are extremely awkward to use in kotlin, because the SAM interface is not the last parameter.

```
aCompletableFutrue.thenComposeAsync(Function<SomeType, CompletableFuture<SomeOtherType>> { 
                               //   ^ WHAT A LONG TYPE NAME THAT NEED TO BE HAND WRITTEN
    // do something that has to be written in multiple lines.
    // for that sake of simplicity I use convert() to represent this process
    convert(it)
}, executor)
```

That `Function` has a very very long generic signature that I don't know how to let IDE generate. It will be a plain in the butt if the type name become even longer or contains a ParameterizedType or has type variance annotations.

<sub>It also looks nasty because of the trailing `, executor)` on line 5.</sub>

Is there some missing functionality in kotlin or IDE that can help with the situation? At least I don't want to write that long SAM constructor all by myself.

---

#### Rejected solutions:

1. Using named parameter doesn't seem to work because this feature only works on a kotlin function.
2. Abandon async methods sounds bad from the very beginning.
3. Kotlin corountine is rejected because we are working with some silly Java libraries that accept `CompletionStage` only.

Comment: You could create extension functions that take proper function types and the executor parameter first. It could be a lot of extension functions you have to make though.

Comment: My thought, too. See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/b8ec0365371721e4a0cbdf2701288799 for an example.

Comment: @marstran Nice thought. But why don't you post it as an anwser...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IF** you calling the api from java that takes a functional interface parameter at last, you can just using lambda in kotlin.

```
val composed: CompletableFuture<String> = aCompletableFutrue.thenComposeAsync { 
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync { it.toString() }
};
```

**Secondly**, if you don't like the java api method signature. you can write your own extension methods, for example:

```
fun <T, U> CompletableFuture<T>.thenComposeAsync(executor: Executor
      , mapping: Function1<in T, out CompletionStage<U>>): CompletableFuture<U> {
    return thenComposeAsync(Function<T,CompletionStage<U>>{mapping(it)}, executor)
}
```

**THEN** you can makes the lambda along the method.

```
aCompletableFutrue.thenComposeAsync(executor){
  // do working
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for giving such a detailed anwser. (I do know about your first point)